# Em qual camada transformar Dominio em DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arquitetura-de-software

Olá, em uma aplicação Asp.Net MVC a arquitetura possui classes de entidade de domínio, DTOs e ViewModels.
A transformação das ViewModels eu faço no controller, até ai tudo bem, mas em qual camada eu devo fazer a transformação de classes de domínio para DTO, é correto um repository retornar DTO ou receber DTO para inserção no banco de dados?
O correto não seria trabalhar com classes de domínio nos services, camada de regras de negócio e repositories e DTO somente nas camadas de apresentação?

Comment: Acho que tudo depende do tamanho do projeto. (Não precisa de um canhão para matar um mosquito). Você pode usar um AutoMapper para fazer a transformação de forma mais desacoplada, pode considerar que somente o controller veja as VMs e com isso tb as DTOs, pode considerar que o controller não veja as DTOs e com isso outra cama veja VMs e com isso as DTOs também.

Comment: Isso ai é bem relativo, mas, tambem depende do tamanho do projeto porque sua arquitetura pode acabar ficando confusa. Isso é dificil de prever em projetos ágeis, tirando o fato de que em alguns projetos ageis o PM/PO tem um misto de visão tecnica e de negócio e consegue passar um rumo para a engenharia. Isso torna a pergunta muito ampla, você pode tentar ser mais sucinto? (talvez exemplos ajudem).